# OAuth not installed on host

Tags: php, oauth

I am trying to get a API to work, and it requires the OAuth

```
$oauth = new OAuth("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

When my host server run this php file, then I get an error that the OAuth is not exist. I do a google search to find a way to install it but no idea.

I find a way where a programmer wrote the OAuth module and then import this module to the index.php but is working with XML, where is something I don't want.

Can anyone with plain English, to explain to me why this problem exist, and how to fix it on a server where you don't have root permissions.

To avoid any bad words: I went to [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) URL and I tried to download and install it on localhost but no result.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists, because OAuth isn't installed in PHP by default. You're correct that you need to install a PECL extension to be able to use it, but if you don't have the privileges to install php extensions on your web host the best thing to do is to ask your host admin to do so.

If this is still not possible then there is little you can do, the only solutions being - changing your web host, or get some other extension, like [this one](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib).

As for the localhost installation, you are on the right track, but maybe you're doing something wrong with your pecl installation? Also, web server logs sometimes provide some insights as to why your installed extension isn't working, like missing dependencies or whatever.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to solve the problem with my host.